# Panel using mouseover, mouseout event in jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have just started learning jQuery and I wrote this code to make a panel which basically shows new div element on mouseover. But, the div element is triggered(slides up and down) multiple number of times on single mouseover. What could be the reason?

```js
//script for project web
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("div#web").bind("mouseover, mouseenter", function() {
    $(this).find(".hover-web").slideDown();
    $("#actionImageWeb").slideUp();
    $(".title-web").slideUp();
  }).bind("mouseout, mouseleave", function() {
    $(this).find(".hover-web").slideUp();
    $("#actionImageWeb").slideDown();
    $(".title-web").slideDown();
  });
});

//script for project training
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("div#training").bind("mouseover, mouseenter", function() {
    $(this).find(".hover-training").slideDown();
    $("#actionImageTraining").slideUp();
    $(".title-training").slideUp();
  }).bind("mouseout, mouseleave", function() {
    $(this).find(".hover-training").slideUp();
    $("#actionImageTraining").slideDown();
    $(".title-training").slideDown();  
  });
});

//script for project workshop
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("div#workshop").bind("mouseover, mouseenter", function() {
    $(this).find(".hover-workshop").slideDown();
    $("#actionImageWorkshop").slideUp();
    $(".title-workshop").slideUp();
  }).bind("mouseout, mouseleave", function() {
    $(this).find(".hover-workshop").slideUp();
    $("#actionImageWorkshop").slideDown();
    $(".title-workshop").slideDown();
  });
});
```

```css
.services-main {
  background-color: #f3efef;
  width: 1000px;
  height: 150px;
  margin-left: 140px;
  float: left;
  box-shadow: 1px 1px 1px #ccc;
  position: relative;
}

img {
  height: 60px;
  width: 60px;
}

.services-title {
  margin-top: 10px;
}

.common {
  display: inline-block;
  padding-left: 90px;
  padding-right: 90px;
  padding-bottom: 5px;
  padding-top: 30px;
  text-align: center;
}

.clear {
  clear: both;
}

.hover {
  height: 150px;
  background-color: white;
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0;
  z-index: 1;
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="services-main">
  <div id="project" class="project common"><img id="actionImageProject" src="project.png">
    <div class="title-project services-title">Projects</div>
    <div class="hover-project hover">
      Lorem, ipsum dolor sit<br> amet consectetur adipisicing elit.
    </div>
  </div>
  <div id="web" class="web common"><img id="actionImageWeb" src="web-programming.png">
    <div class="title-web services-title">Web</div>
    <div class="hover-web hover">
      Lorem, ipsum dolor sit<br> amet consectetur adipisicing elit.
    </div>
  </div>
  <div id="training" class="training common"><img id="actionImageTraining" src="training.png">
    <div class="title-training services-title">Training</div>
    <div class="hover-training hover">
      Lorem, ipsum dolor sit<br> amet consectetur adipisicing elit.
    </div>
  </div>
  <div id="workshop" class="workshop common"><img id="actionImageWorkshop" src="presentation.png">
    <div class="title-workshop services-title">Workshop</div>
    <div class="hover-workshop hover">
      Lorem, ipsum dolor sit<br> amet consectetur adipisicing elit.
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="clear"></div>
<script type="text/javascript">
  $(document).ready(function() {

    $("div#project").bind("mouseover, mouseenter", function() {


      $(this).find(".hover-project").slideDown();
      $("#actionImageProject").slideUp();
      $(".title-project").slideUp();

    }).bind("mouseout, mouseleave", function() {

      $(this).find(".hover-project").slideUp();
      $("#actionImageProject").slideDown();
      $(".title-project").slideDown();

    });

  });
</script>
<script type="text/javascript">
</script>
<script type="text/javascript">
</script>
<script type="text/javascript">
</script>

</html>
```

I expect the four different panels to trigger according only when we hover over them and don't get disturbed by each other.

Here is what I tried: https://codepen.io/anon/pen/XwQBKR

Comment: `the different existing elements are also triggered by mouseoever even when they are not called` I can't replicate this behaviour in your codepen. Also a couple of thing. First, `bind()` is deprecated. Use `on()` instead. Secon, event names should be separated with spaces, not a comma.

Comment: Also note that you can DRY your logic up by using common classes instead of ids. Then you only need to write the hover logic once for all instances, not repeated multiple times.

Comment: Thank you for your advice that sure helps but there is still the issue of the div section sliding up multiple times on single mouseover and the div elements spacing being disturbed.

Comment: Do you mean when you quickly move the mouse back and forth between sections and the animation continues happening?

Comment: On mouseover project section the div element slides up multiple times when mouse is stationary. It also disturbs the alignment and spacing of other sections